# Is there simple software that could perform proximity searches?

Tags: microsoft-word, search, regex

I am reading through quite a few state statutes and I need to see if there are any instances where two words come together frequently, such as

- flow meter
- flow-based meter
- meter based on the flow

Some sort of RegEx searcher would be extremely helpful in this situation, because all I really need is something that can show me

> flow AROUND(10) meter

MS Word apparently doesn't have any function to perform these kind of proximity searches, is there anything out there that could help?

Comment: What have you tried? I can think of a few different ways of solving this, most involving regexes, but it'd help a lot to know what tools you've looked at using, in order to tailor my response to your situation.

Comment: @AaronMiller I've tried a few things in Word such as [F,f]low*{1,50}[M,m]eter, but I feel like I am relearning RegExes all over again for Word. I don't mind using RegExes, but what can I use to perform RegEx searches? I am at work and I don't have administrative rights on this computer.

Comment: This might be overkill but FileLocator Pro supports a similar syntax, e.g. flow NEAR:10 meter.

Comment: Although the question is unfortunately closed, you should check out the addin I created, [Wordiscover](http://wordiscover.cint.io)

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is regex searching in a Windows text editor, take a look at Notepad++. It can do regex searches/replaces and comes in a portable form so you won't need admin rights to install it.

It can also search through all open files and present you with a summary of matches.

Comment: If I understand the OP's intent (something related to technical or academic documents), then this solution, while possible, could be cumbersome, mostly due to formatting issues. Can you provide an example usage of your proposal, as to illustrate your solution?

Comment: I completely agree that it's possible formatting might get in the way, but we don't have any sample material to go on (yet).I would hope that whatever format these documents are provided in could be saved to plain text. If that is the case, all documents can be opened at once and then the search performed (the OP is happy to write regexes)

Comment: From my experience, ***any*** document can be saved in plain text - it might not be easy to read it afterwards, but it can be saved.